# How do I show only a static amount of values in my XYLineChart domain axis?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to make a [Bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) with JFreeChart and I need to set an static amount of values in my domain axis. As you can see in this [picture](http://www.ib.cnea.gov.ar/~instyctl/Tutorial_Matlab_esp/PIbode.gif), I ALWAYS need to show only: 0.01; 0.1; 1; 10; 100 and 1000 and i need the graphic to adjust to this domain.

Comment: Did a search `jfreechart axis label` not get you anywhere?

Comment: Have a look at the class `ValueAxis`, you should be able to set user-specified axis-ticks using this object and it's `subclasses`

Comment: @StefanFalk sorry, i've been looking for an answer since yersterday and couldn't find one.

Comment: @DanielMac that's what i've been doing, i'll keep trying to find the solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach. Some examples are seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10347674/230513).