# JFreeChart format Y-axis to show values in Power

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

How to format y-axis to show values as 5*10^5, 1*10^6, 2*10^6... instead of 500,000,1,000,000, 2,000,000... and which are divisible by 5 or 10?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`LogAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogAxis.html) with the default tick units seems to work. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353270/230513) uses integer tick units.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.LogAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450677/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353270/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private static final int N = 7;

    private void display() {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Series");
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
            series.add(i, Math.pow(10, i));
        }
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("X");
        xAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        LogAxis yAxis = new LogAxis("Y");
        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(new XYSeriesCollection(series),
            xAxis, yAxis, new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false));
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
            "Chart", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, false);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(480, 240);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is it possible to show the power value as 10 power 3 instead of 10^3?

Comment: If you mean like 10³, you might try [this](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116638)?

Comment: could you please update the code to attributedString, I am not able to figure out, how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I've not used it either, you might look [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/search.php?keywords=AttributedString) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributedString+%5Bjfreechart%5D). You might also pose a new question with an [mctre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that show your intended usage.

Comment: @user3215852: I found this [example[](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116592#p176675) for the axis label, but I'm not sure about the tick labels themselves.

Comment: its only for axis labels, I am not able to set it for tick labels.