# Adding a JChart to a panel

Tags: java, jfreechart

Im new to using APIs.
I am trying to get a chart showing on a panel.
I have already set up the libs and they are working.
The API im using is JFreeCharts.

I made a class called JChart:

```
 public class JChart extends JFrame
 {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public JChart(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) 
  {

        // This will create the dataset 
        PieDataset dataset = createDataset();
        // based on the dataset we create the chart
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, chartTitle);
        // we put the chart into a panel
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        // default size
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 150));



    }



/**
     * Creates a sample dataset 
     */

    private  PieDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
        result.setValue("Linux", 29);
        result.setValue("Mac", 20);
        result.setValue("Windows", 51);
        return result;

    }


/**
     * Creates a chart
     */

    private JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset, String title) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(title,          // chart title
            dataset,                // data
            true,                   // include legend
            true,
            false);

        PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setStartAngle(290);
        plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
        plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
        return chart;

    }

}
```

In my form I have a method:

```
  private void LoadMyGraphs()
    {     
        JChart chart = new JChart("name", "title");
        myGraphPanel.add(chart); 

    }
```

I am getting no errors, but the panel does not change. 
I can changed the background color of the panel so I know nothing is wring in that respect.
Any info would be amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At some point you must add the `ChartPanel` to a container in the enclosing frame, e.g.

```
this.add(chartPanel);
```

As an aside, also consider overriding `getPreferredSize()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450677/230513) and suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). More examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I can not get it to work. thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.