# Having Custom Labels on Y axis on an XY Dataset - JFreechart

Tags: java, charts, plot, jfreechart

I have the following XY Chart [image]

where the X axis are days and Y axis are the IDs of the elements that i want to represent. 
The problem is that the IDs that I am trying to represent has a vast range, say 0-50000, but not all of the values in that range occur on the plot every time. Say an average 10-20 values in that range might be on the plot each time it is generated. But these values are spread across the range. As you look at the attached figure, majority of the values are towards the lower end of the range (100-2000) and few values above the 10000 mark, because of which the graph is looking very skewed. And also I am actually passing the IDs as it is as the Y co-ordinate for the Y axis.

I just wanted to know if there's a way where i can have a custom Y axis, where i can map the actual IDs to an intermediate index (for just the 10 items which i want to display) and use the actual IDs as custom labels  on the Y axis after plotting?

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe a `org.jfree.chart.axis.LogAxis`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22450677/230513).

Comment: Yeah, but my values are not exactly Logarithmic values :(

Comment: You could get the output you want if you do the mapping to an index value (0 to N-1 where N is the number of values in your range that you need to plot) *before* you populate your dataset (in other words, the y-values will be the index rather than the actual data value).  Then change the y-axis on the XYPlot to a SymbolAxis, and set the symbols to the actual data values corresponding to the indices.

Comment: Genius ! SymbolAxis is the one i was hunting for, working perfectly. Thank you very much @DavidGilbert, can you make it as an answer? I will upvote and accept it ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the output you want if you do the mapping to an index value (0 to N-1 where N is the number of values in your range that you need to plot) before you populate your dataset (in other words, the y-values will be the index rather than the actual data value). Then change the y-axis on the XYPlot to a SymbolAxis, and set the symbols to the actual data values corresponding to the indices.