# Logarithmic scale with jFreeChart BoxAndWhiskerChart

Tags: jfreechart

I've got a box and whisker chart being populated like so:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBoxAndWhiskerChart(
             "Average Fitness",
             "Generation",
             "Fitness",
             aveDataSet,
             true);
ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Average Fitness", chart);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

But the scale of the data makes the chart hard to read. At the left of the x-axis, the values are in the neighborhood of 250 000 000, but by about the halfway point the values are below 10 (but still converging toward 0). This long-tail convergence is impossible to see with the linear y-axis, but I can't figure if I'm able to replace it with a log scale.

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10353270/230513)?

Comment: That's the idea of the log scale, but I'm trying to apply it specifically to a BoxAndWhiskerChart. It looks like the ChartFactory options aren't as customizable as building a chart from scratch, so I'm figuring it out now though! Thanks.

Comment: Heres a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513) with which to experiment.