# How to control the increments of values on the Y-Axis of BarChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am attempting to make uniform my barchart which ranges in a wide number of values.  I have attempted to adjust the tick and other ranges.  Essentially, I would like to increase the increments on the yAxis to fit all the bars proportionately.  Any ideas?

Also, I should note that instead of NumberAxis, I get ValueAxis.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking - are you looking to make the y-axis [log scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347674/logarithmic-axis-labels-ticks-customization)?

Comment: Never use 3-d bars. They are useless decorations and make it difficult to see what the actual value is.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @copeg.  Yes, I would like to make the graph log scale but unfortunately I do not have access to NumberAxis.

Comment: Your image shows a `NumberAxis`; used `LogAxis` instead; for additional guidance, edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I ended up getting the values to square up including setting the RangeAxis range dynamically.  I also removed the 3d elements on suggestion of @FredK.  I am using a DefaultCategoryDataSet (plot is a CategoryPlot), so the code below is appropriate for these conditions...

```
  LogAxis yAxis = new LogAxis("Transaction Time (ms)");

        yAxis.setBase(10);
        plot.setRangeAxis(yAxis);
        yAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
        yAxis.setMinorTickMarksVisible(true);
        yAxis.setAutoRange(true);
        plot.setRangeAxis(yAxis);
        plot.getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));

        Double maximum = (Double) DatasetUtilities.findMaximumRangeValue(dataset);

        plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(10);
        plot.getRangeAxis().setUpperBound(maximum * 1.6);
```